# Android : get a unique id on each app to rate a service only once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a restaurant app showing profiles of the chefs we got...

I set a Firebase database where users can rate each chef..
yet I want to get a unique id for each installation of the app which is persistent with time, so that a user  can re-submit a rate for a chef yet he's contributing to the whole rate only once..

is there such an id ?
is there a better way to do so?

thanks in advance, great people..

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your users sign in with Firebase Authentication, you'd typically use their UID for this purpose.

That would prevent them from rating the same check multiple times, even if they use the same app on multiple devices, or reinstall it on the same device.

If you're not (yet) using Firebase Authentication, I'd recommend adding it for this use-case anyway. You can use it without requiring your users to sign in, by [using anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). This is as simple as calling:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

But follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously) to ensure you don't create a new UID every time the app runs.